# Why did I get this error when I send an email with PEAR Net_SMTP module?

Tags: php, email, pear

I get this error when sending emails with the [PEAR `Net_SMTP` module](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_SMTP):

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Net_SMTP::getGreeting() in /home/test/Mail/smtp.php on line 316

Comment: Because the class `NET_SMTP` has no method `getGreeting()`. Probably a version mismatch.

Comment: Maybe because the method `getGreeting()` is not present in the class `Net_SMTP` and it's called from _/home/test/Mail/smtp.php on line 316_ ?

Comment: Pecka, it does, just in versions greater to `1.3.3`

Comment: Don't mean to sound like a broken record, but I'd hazard a guess that you installed those manually? If you install pear packages manually, you're doing it wrong!Use the pear installer (pear command) it will handle package dependencies, including versions of those packages, so you don't run in this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might have an out dated version of `Net_SMTP`

In V1.4.4 we have that method like so:

```
/*
   * @since   1.3.3
*/
function getGreeting()
{
    return $this->_greeting;
}
```

But as you can see it was only add in V`1.3.3` so you must have that version or greater.

[@Source](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_SMTP/docs/1.4.4/__filesource/fsource_Net_SMTP__Net_SMTP-1.4.4SMTP.php.html#a360)